# Protect against Nil in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm doing a codewar where you need to find the sum of positive numbers in an array. I was able to find a solution except for when the test arrays are empty or all the elements are negative. How to I return 0 instead of nil?

Here is my solution...

```
def positive_sum(arr)

    arr.select {|x| x > 0}.reduce :+

end
```

Comment: Starting with Ruby 2.3, you can also use `select(&:positive)` instead of `select { |x| x > 0 }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to do both `select` and `reduce`. You can check the value of `x` in your `reduce` block:

```
def positive_sum(arr)
  arr.reduce(0) do |sum, x|
    if x > 0
      sum + x
    else
      sum
    end
  end
end

positive_sum([10, -3, 20, -8])
# => 30

positive_sum([])
# => 0

positive_sum([-1, -5])
# => 0
```

Of course, you can make this a oneliner if you prefer:

```
def positive_sum(arr)
  arr.reduce(0) {|sum, x| x > 0 ? sum + x : sum }
end
```

Comment: Very elegant!! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Your solution is pretty elegant already as it captures the essence of what you want to achieve and is pretty readable.

The one missing piece is that you can define a starting value to your reduce call and pass the operation as a block (which is the more common style anyway). When passing a starting value, it will be set as `sum` on the first call of the block. If you omit this value, `sum` will be set to the first value of the array and `x` to the second one.

Thus, the full code can look like this:

```
arr.select { |x| x > 0 }.reduce(0, &:+)
```

This is the short form of

```
arr.select { |x| x > 0 }.reduce(0) { |sum, x| sum + x }
```

Answer (score 1):

In ruby 2.3.0 the method [positive?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Numeric.html#method-i-positive-3F) has been introduced, with `select` and `map`.

```
def positive_sum(array)
    return 0 if array.nil? || array.empty? 
    array.select(&:positive?).inject(0) { |sum, num| sum + num } 
end
```

if you're not using Ruby 2.3.0+ you can use this

```
def positive_sum(array)
    return 0 if array.nil? || array.empty? 
    array.inject(0) { |sum, num| num > 0 ? sum + num : sum } 
end
```